# Error on Extjs TabPanel

Tags: extjs

i get this error in Firebug

```
instantiate()ext-debug.js (line 6634)
alias()ext-debug.js (line 2448)
app.js()app.js (line 9)
c is not a constructor
this.instantiators[length] = new Function('c', 'a', 'return new c('+args.join(',')+')');
```

Where it traces to my app.js file on line 9 where i create a tabPanel

```
var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    region: 'center',
    id: 'centerPanel',
        items: [{
            title: 'Center Panel',
            autoScroll: true,
        }]
});
```

I've removed all the code from inside the panel but i still get the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Nicos

Comment: it looks fine from here.. can you show us more code?

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal you have an unused comma for the item ?

```
var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    region: 'center',
    id: 'centerPanel',
        items: [{
            title: 'Center Panel',
            autoScroll: true  ,  <<<====== here the comma is unused
        }]
});
```

Comment: its a 'leftover' from removing all the items from inside the panel. i removed it but it still didn't work. same error